# Unable to get all values for recommendations using Get-AzAdvisorRecommendation powershell cmdlet

Tags: azure, powershell

I am writting script which is getting all recommendations from Azure Advisor and sending all of the info by email.
However I can't find from which variable I can get info: "*Consider deleting your resource*" for *Unused/Empty App service plan*.

From Azure portal:
[recommended actions in Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp10F.png)

Code which I'm using:
`$resType = Get-AzAdvisorRecommendation | Where-Object {$_.Category -eq 'Cost'}`

and to limit to only one recommendation:
`($resType | where {$_.ImpactedValue -eq 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'}) | select -Property *`

results:
[code results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCpp2.png)

and if I go to extended property there is nothing there:
[extended property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7c1o.png)

Any idea from where I can grab that info?

thanks

With other recommendations like VMs reservations, Extended property display a lot of information. But this doesn't work for Unused/Empty App service plan.

Comment: See what you get with following Get-AzAdvisorRecommendation |  Select-Object -Property *

Comment: @jdweng I've got the same what above but for all recommendations.

Comment: See if following give more info : Get-AzAdvisorRecommendation | Select-Object -Property Category | Format-List  OR  Write-Host (((Get-AzAdvisorRecommendation).Category).GetType())

Comment: @jdweng
1. Get-AzAdvisorRecommendation | Select-Object -Property Category | Format-List :
Category : Cost
Category : Cost
Category : Cost
Category : Cost
Category : Cost
Category : Cost
Category : Cost
Category : Security
Category : Security
Category : Security
Category : Security
Category : Security
displays all categories

Comment: @jdweng
Write-Host (((Get-AzAdvisorRecommendation).Category).GetType()) returned System.Object[]

Comment: Category is an array with some of the values Cost and the other is Security.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.advisor/get-azadvisorrecommendation?view=azps-10.3.0#example-1-list-recommendation-by-subscriptionid-and-resource-group-name

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerShell only below property details are available:

```
$x=Get-AzAdvisorRecommendation | Where-Object {$_.Category -eq 'Cost' -and $_.ShortDescriptionProblem -eq 'Unused/Empty App Service plan'} | Format-List -Property * 
$x
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

You will get **`Extended properties`** when you use CLI commands like below:

```
$x=az advisor recommendation list --category Cost                   
$x
```

**`Output:`**

[image]